# save as excel file with different format, xml spreadsheet 2003 to xls or xlsx

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, clr, ole

i have a sql server 2008 job which creating excel file  with dll.
dll using [xmlwriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) to create excel file.
It's creating xml spreadsheet 2003  file

Problem is file too large about 250mb

```
CREATE  ASSEMBLY [myclr]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM  'myclr.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe;
GO
```

what i have tried:

- removed some  xml attributes from xmlwriter but still too large
- [openxml](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)

> problem openxml using    Windows.base.dll which cannot register to sql server because it's not [supported dlls](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/119429/)

- oledb

> [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706359/writing-multiple-tables-on-same-excel-sheet-with-oledb)

- microsoft.office.interop

> client doesnt want to set up office to server

Now my solution is  i will write a windows service and its will open and save as excel file.
which i wrote with microsoft.office.interop 
but i need another way to do it.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass _Excel = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WB = null;
        // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet WS = null;
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        try
        {

            _Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Open(path,
                missing, missing, missing, missing,
                missing, missing, missing, missing,
                missing, missing, missing, missing,
                missing, missing);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WB.Close(false, missing, missing);

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            _Excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            WB.SaveAs(path, 
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8,
                      missing, missing, missing, missing,                                  
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
                      XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,  
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
                      XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing);
            _Excel.Quit();

        }
```

- openxml

  ```
    using (SpreadsheetDocument ssd = 
                  SpreadsheetDocument.Open("myfile.xls", true)) 
      {
          WorkbookPart wbPart = ssd.WorkbookPart;
          WorksheetPart worksheetPart = wbPart.WorksheetParts.First();


          worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
          wbPart.Workbook.Save();
          ssd.Close();
      }
  ```

> File contains corrupted data

note:long post sorry ,no potato

Comment: Have you tried ClosedXml? https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/. I don't think generating Excel files from within SQL Server by using CLR objects is a good idea. Why not generating it from an external program such as a console app?

Comment: A 250MB spreadsheet?  I would re-think my strategy.